# Send a socket with Socket java library

Tags: java, tcp, serversocket

I am trying to open a TCP connection between two machines which are not within the same LAN. **the server does not receive anything** even though it has opened the port with port forwarding in the router settings.
p**robably the client does not connect to the host**, this is because having put a **test sout** after the socket initialization instruction, **in the debug, in the console, nothing appears**, on the contrary, the connection drops after a certain period (about 15 seconds ):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

and I'm trying to figure out just where the error lies.

Client.java

```
        try {
           
            Socket s = new Socket("00.00.00.000", 6666);
            System.out.println("connected");
            s.getOutputStream().write((int) (Math.random() * 10));
            s.close();
          
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            uhe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Server.java

```
 try {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
    while (true) {
        Socket s = ss.accept();        
        System.out.println("Server: " + s.getInputStream().read());     
        s.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Port Forwarding in server router settings:
[image]

Comment: For one: yes the client never reaches the host. Can you ping the host? How did you find out the hosts WAN IP?

Comment: @DownloadPizza yes the host is reachable, i can ping it, but what do you mean for "How did you find out the hosts WAN IP"?

Comment: You have the hosts real IP where you have 00.00.00.000, right?

Comment: And not just 192.168.1.29

Comment: @DownloadPizza yes, that is just a censure

Comment: @DownloadPizza no i have the real public ip

Comment: I assume the server is some VPS you rented. Maybe check firewall settings on the server? Best guess is that they are using ufw, so `ufw status` might tell you something. If its not ufw you may need to search

Comment: @DownloadPizza no it is just another pc in another LAN, is the pc of a my friend

Comment: Ok then I actually have no idea. To me it seems like you did everything right. Maybe check if their ISP actually supports port forwarding? My router for example has a port forwarding page which does not do anything, I needed DMZ settings to get server things to run. A quick google search might tell you, but in my case it didnt so trial and error might be the only way

Comment: It looks like those router settings are forwarding port 6666 on the router to port 113 on the destination, but the server is actually binding to port 6666 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved allowing access to private and public networks in the **Windows client firewall settings**

[image]